# string date needs format

Tags: c#

I have a string date like so:

```
var sDate = '3/3/2012'
```

It eventually goes into a DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, "MM/dd/yyyy")
and it fails because of the missing leading zeros.

What's the best way to add the leading zeros?

I know TryParse would have worked but can't refactor at the moment.

Comment: FWIW, there's an overload for .ParseExact that can take an array of acceptable date formats.  [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What's the best way to add the leading zeros?

Why would you do that? Just use `ParseExact` with the format it's *actually* got, which is `M/d/yyyy`.

The whole point of the format string is to let you declare the format of your data - not to make you *change* the format of your data.

Note that you can specify multiple patterns with [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx), so you could always pass in both `M/d/yyyy` *and* `MM/dd/yyyy`. I believe `M/d/yyyy` will work with zero-padded ones anyway though...

Comment: Thanks Jon for sharing your insight.

Comment: @Rod Also (what I learned from the answerer recently) remember to use the `InvariantCulture` in which the special character `/` in the format string translates to `/` itself. Or escape the slash to make it a literal character, as in `@"M\/d\/yyyy"`.